# CAS server only accepts requests from localhost

Tags: java, localhost, ip-address, cas

I'm using CAS server to handle authentication for my web apps within Tomcat server, and everything works fine when I send requests from localhost like: https://localhost:8443/WebApp.

But if I want to send request from my virtual machine for example, I would use private network IPv4 address of my host and that would look like: https://192.168.1.13:8443/WebApp.

But I get an exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized server name : 192.168.1.13:8443`

I tried editing hosts file on Windows by adding: 192.168.1.13 localhost, but no help. I also changed server name property in `cas.properties` from http://localhost:8080 to https://192.168.1.13:8443 but also no help.

My question is, how can I make CAS server to accept requests that are not from localhost? It won't accept even from 127.0.0.1, only if it says localhost?

Full stack trace:

```
мар 18, 2022 7:31:15 ПО ПОДНЕ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rest.api.CASServlet] in context with path [/Documents] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized server name : 192.168.1.13:8443
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.Util.getService(Util.java:72)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.getService(CASFilter.java:492)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.redirectToCAS(CASFilter.java:513)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

мар 18, 2022 7:31:15 ПО ПОДНЕ org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/Documents] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized server name : 192.168.1.13:8443
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.Util.getService(Util.java:72)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.getService(CASFilter.java:492)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.redirectToCAS(CASFilter.java:513)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: Seems as if IPs are disallowed. Also IP on HTTPs is a bad idea. See: https://www.w3.org/Addressing/BNF.html#5 for hostnames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried editing hosts file on Windows by adding: 192.168.1.13 localhost, but no help. I also changed server name property in cas.properties from http://localhost:8080 to https://192.168.1.13:8443 but also no help.

Yes, none of this is relevant.

> My question is, how can I make CAS server to accept requests that are not from localhost?

You don't and you can't because the problem is not with the CAS server. Your logs show that the request is stopped when it reaches your application first:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unrecognized server name : 192.168.1.13:8443
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.Util.getService(Util.java:72)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.getService(CASFilter.java:492)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.redirectToCAS(CASFilter.java:513)
    at edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
```

Note the word `cas.client` in there. This means, there is nothing in the CAS server that would be modified because you need to fix the client application to accept requests correctly.

CAS does not care where the request comes from for the most part (except in very very special circumstances).

PS Your logs also show that your CAS-enabled application is using `edu.yale.its.tp.cas.client` which is an ancient version of the Java CAS client  library that has been discontinued and has not been patched, updated or modified for well over 15 years. You may wish to reconsider.